# Using QT For Creating a Screen Dimmer

Tags: qt

I'm trying to implement a screen dimmer using QT4 and I wanted some advice before I get cracking instead of going into this blindly.

I want to create a top-level window that has no frame. I was thinking of making the background black and messing with the opacity so that it will dim the screen out after the system is idle for a given period of time.

The problem with this is that if this window is always on top, how can I pass click events to the window underneath it? I'm not the least bit familiar with the windows API (the solution only has to work under windows), but I'm guessing that's a good place to start. Can anyone point me to some useful classes/functions or suggest another way of doing this via QT?

Comment: so you need to pass events to a different application, not the same, right?

Comment: I would suggest not passing the clicks.  Instead, keep the window hidden until necessary, and when it is shown, use the first click to hide it (and just eat the click).

Comment: @hexa: yes, it would be an entirely different application

Comment: @cjhuitt: the window must remain visible and top-level at all times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested in the solution I came up with and the windows API functions I used, you can check out my blog posting here: http://sarcastichacker.com/getnextwindowandgetforegroundwindow

I will be updating the source and making another related posting on the same blog within the next couple of days.